# GIven below is a c++ code from Cp3 book. I am unable to understand this line:-scanf("0.%[0-9]...\n", &x);

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain me the use of `.%[0-9]` in the above statement.

This is the problem statement:

> The first line of input is an integer N. This is followed by N lines,
>   each starting with the character ‘0’, followed by a dot ‘.’, then
>   followed by an unknown number of digits (up to 100 digits), and
>   finally terminated with three dots ‘...’.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int N; 
char x[110]; 

int main() {
scanf("%d\n", &N);

while (N--) {                 // we simply loop from N, N-1, N-2, ..., 0
scanf("0.%[0-9]...\n", &x);   // ‘&’ is optional when x is a char array
printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", x);
} } // return 0;
```

Input for the code:-

```
3

0.1227...

0.517611738...

0.7341231223444344389923899277...
```

Output for the code:-

```
the digits are 0.1227

the digits are 0.517611738

the digits are 0.7341231223444344389923899277
```

Comment: Why is a C++ book showing `scanf`?  It appears to be using a non-standard extension to the `scanf` format string.  Get a [better book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @MartinBonner `scanf` is part of c++.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: @doug Yes, I know that.  So are a lot of things.  The question is why is a C++ book which is obviously for beginners (note the comment on the decrementing while loop) showing it.

Comment: Eek!  Following the link in Botje's answer, `[` is not non-standard.  I never knew that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my copy of `man scanf` ([other reference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)), although apparently it was part of C89 already.

```
   [      Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set
          of  accepted  characters;  the next pointer must be a pointer to
          char, and there must be enough room for all  the  characters  in
          the  string,  plus  a  terminating null byte.
```

To make it concrete: in your case the call to `scanf` matches a literal `0`, a literal `.`, and stores the remaining digits (the `[0-9]` part) into the `char*` pointed to by `x`.